# Allow us to filter out tag-only or minimal edits from Suggested Edits review

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Over the past few months, I have seen on multiple occasions new users policing questions (correcting tags, removing salutations, etc.,) without substantially improving the questions, even when there are glaring problems in them (lack of code formatting, grammar problems, etc.).

When I go to the review section and see a flood of items in the Suggested Edits section, and then have to review minor edit after minor edit, I find my time wasted. I have only a limited number of edits I can review, and if there are substantial edits in the queue, I might miss them because somebody edited the tags on 20 questions. Earlier, I used to reject tag edits out of hand, but I started skipping such minor edits when I found my limit for the day reached on multiple occasions. I do stop for edits which seem to correct multiple problems, or fix the only problem with a post. (That's to say, I *do* look at the changes, but skip the question if I find them too minor, but correct.) The problem with skipping is that I can't go back to those edits once I have exhausted any potential diamonds in the rough that the queue might have had.

So, what I'd like is to filter for tag-only or minor (say, <20 chars changed, content only deleted). This way, once I have reviewed substantial edits, I can go back, turn off the filter and let the floodgates open.